# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError в чем может быть проблема

Tags: java, apache, javafx, apache-poi, commonjs

Прога которая читает мп3 теги и записывает в ListView не работает как исправить эту ошибку(хотя бы из-за чего она возникает)?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.parser.Parser;
import org.apache.tika.parser.mp3.Mp3Parser;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Main extends Application {

    private Button button;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        String fileLocation = "D:\\music";
        File dir = new File(fileLocation);
        button = new Button("Check");
        button.setOnAction( e-> readFiles(dir));
        VBox box = new VBox(button);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(box,300,300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static void readFiles(File baseDirectory) {

        List<Mp3data> mp3data = new ArrayList<Mp3data>();
        ObservableList<Mp3data> langs = FXCollections.observableArrayList(mp3data);
        ListView<Mp3data> langsListView = new ListView<Mp3data>(langs);

        try {

            Iterator<File> iterator = FileUtils.iterateFiles(baseDirectory, new String[]{"mp3"}, true);
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                File fileloop = iterator.next();

                InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileloop);
                ContentHandler handler = new DefaultHandler();
                Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
                Parser parser = new Mp3Parser();
                ParseContext parseCtx = new ParseContext();
                parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, parseCtx);

                input.close();

                String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();

                Mp3data track = new Mp3data();
                track.setArtist(metadata.get("xmpDM:artist"));
                track.setAlbum(metadata.get("xmpDM:album"));
                track.setTitle(metadata.get("title"));
                track.setDuration(toMinutes(metadata.get("xmpDM:duration")));
                track.setPath(fileloop.getAbsolutePath());

                mp3data.add(track);
                langs.add(track);

            }
            FlowPane root = new FlowPane(langsListView);
            Collections.sort(mp3data);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,600);
            Stage window = new Stage();
            window.setTitle("first");
            window.setScene(scene);
            window.show();
//

        } catch (IOException | SAXException | TikaException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


//        String artist = null;
//        String album = null;
//        for (Mp3data data : mp3data)
//            if (!data.getArtist().equals(artist))
//
//
//
//                if (!data.getAlbum().equals(album))


    }
```

Ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.skipFully(Ljava/io/InputStream;J)J
    at org.apache.tika.parser.mp3.MpegStream.skipFrame(MpegStream.java:164)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.mp3.Mp3Parser.getAllTagHandlers(Mp3Parser.java:212)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.mp3.Mp3Parser.parse(Mp3Parser.java:70)
    at sample.Main.readFiles(Main.java:75)
    at sample.Main.lambda$start$0(Main.java:43)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Какая у вас версия JDK?

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь то 1.8.0_181

Comment: Да, точно 1.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас, вероятнее всего, так называемый jarhell. Это путаница с зависимостями библиотек. Чаще всего такая ошибка возникает, когда в classpath приложения, во время исполнения, попадают одинаковые библиотеки с разными версиями. Либо группа библиотек, которые должны быть одной версии, но по какой-то причине версии у них не совпадают. В таких случаях обычно помогает поиск класса, на который ругается программа по всему проекту (включая зависимости) и анализ библиотек (jar), в которых данный класс фигурирует. Так же внимательно читаем pom.xml/build.gradle/где-у-вас-там-описаны-зависимости на предмет версий библиотек.

Comment: а где найти pom.xml??

Comment: В корне проекта обычно, если Вы maven используете.

Comment: а если я ничего не использую ни maven ни gradle